# I can't run my Application from test directory in a modular maven project (in IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, maven-3, modular

I am programming some java classes, which will be used from other modules to display a google map in JavaFX 14.0.1. These java classes are not a stand alone application, therefore I need an application java class in my test folder to initialise and use my map classes I mentioned (the application class is really just for me/development). However, running the application class from the test directory results in an error I can't get rid off. I am using maven 3, IntelliJ, JavaFX 14.0.1 and my project is a modular maven project. This means I have a module-info.java file in my source code.

Here is my project file structure:

```
myProject
---.idea
---logs
---src
------main
----------java (marked as Sources Root)
---------------ch.XXXX.gmapsfx
--------------------someMapClass1.java
---------------module-info.java

------test
----------java (marked as Test Sources Root)
---------------ch.XXXX.test.gmapsfx
--------------------GMapsFXApp.java


---pom.xml
---myProject.iml
```

When I earlier used the GMapsFXApp in the ch.XXXX.gmapsfx package, then everything works fine. But now when I want to run it in ch.XXXX.test.gmapsfx, then I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x23c2d7a9) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x23c2d7a9
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
at ch.eswitch.test.XXXX.GMapsFXApp.start(GMapsFXApp.java:25)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application ch.XXXX.test.gmapsfx.GMapsFXApp
```

The module-info.java:

```
module myProject {
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.web;
requires javafx.swing;

requires de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialicons;
requires org.controlsfx.controls;
requires GMapsFX;
requires yyyy;

requires jdk.jsobject;


opens ch.XXXX.gmapsfx to javafx.fxml;
opens ch.XXXX.gmapsfx.html;
exports ch.XXXX.gmapsfx;
}
```

After reading countless posts about similiar errors (but not same context) I assume it has something to do with class paths and module paths, but I am still very confused about the idea of these paths and what they mean. I have tried modifying the VM Options in IntelliJ, but it didn't solve my problem. I have tried maven-surefire-plugin, but it didn't work. Maybe I tried them the wrong way or I am completely on the wrong track here. I thank you in advance for your answer and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This is because Maven does a lot of wizardry to get tests working in the context of the module system. It seems to put all code on the classpath when it is executing a test but this does not work well for JavaFX. I had the same problem and it was one of the reasons I abandoned this module system completely. I was just not willing to constantly spend endless hours to get this JPMS running without any visual benefit.

Comment: I came up with a work around. Just unmark the test/java as Test Sources Root and then mark it as Sources Root. Now we have two Sources Root. Then in the module-info.java export the package from the test/java and it works.

Does anyone have a clear explanation why this works now?